# Problem with a deferencable iterator only with visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, iterator

I have this bit of code to remove certain element in my `std::vector`:

```
splitVector.erase(splitVector.begin());
if ( (splitVector.end())->length() == 0 )
    splitVector.erase(splitVector.end());
```

This code works fine on MacOs but on windows it just give me this error :

> Expression: vector iterator not deferencable

I don't understand why this operation works for one os and gives error on other since it's pretty basic.
Anyone has any idea why this occurs?
Also should I still keep using `std::vector` or move to one of the boost container ?

Thanks

Comment: Should `splitVector` be pressumed to be a `std::vector<T*>` where `T::length()` exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to realise that vector::end is not the last item in the vector. It's one past the last item. If you try to dereference it then your program is bugged. Windows is helpfully telling you this, MacOS unhelpfully didn't. Suggest you read up on how to use containers and iterators in the standard library. If you don't understand the basics then moving to boost is unlikely to help you.

Perhaps what you were trying to do is this

```
if ((splitVector.end() - 1)->length() == 0)
  splitVector.erase(splitVector.end() - 1);
```

Comment: I guess I deserved that.Thanks

Comment: After erasing begin, don't forget to check if `end() - 1` still exists. The vector could be empty!

Comment: @Lollancf37: Sorry, my tone really sucked.

Comment: I already check if the vector is empty thanks all. @john no worries, besides that your reply was quick and precise, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

```
  if ( (splitVector.end())->length() == 0 )
```

This simply invokes undefined behavior (UB), because `iterator` returned by `end()` is not dereferenceable.

It works on one platform and not on other is precisely because its UB which means anything can happen; there are infinite number of possibilities, and none of them is guaranteed by the language specification.

Also, `splitVector.end()` is not an iterator to the *last* element. Its *past-the-last-element* iterator. What you actually want is this:

```
 splitVector.erase(splitVector.begin());
 if(!splitVector.empty() && (splitVector.begin() + splitVector.size()-1 )->length() == 0 )
    splitVector.erase(splitVector.begin() + splitVector.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to get back on my books on this one.

Comment: @Nawaz: if the `splitVector` is empty after the `erase`, you're still in UB.

Comment: @Matthieu: Oops. I didn't check for that. Edited. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: That's why I really appreciate the fact that the Dirkunmare team introduced so many debug checks in their STL, it's definitely too easy to mess up :/

Comment: @Nawaz: Dirkumware (not Dirunmare...) is the company from which the MSVC STL comes from (before adaptation I think). They have taken pain to add supplementary checks (like the assert shown by the OP) on about all the *Undefined Behavior* that the standard mentionned (Iterator Invalidation, Range validation, etc...). For example, see: Checked Iterators at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28v=VS.80%29.aspx  (warning, it may slow down the program considerably)

Answer (score 4):

Containers like `std::vector<T>` define half-open ranges, i.e. the `end()` iterator points to memory *behind* the last element. It means, there is no deferencable object.

What you want to do is probably

```
if (!splitVector.empty() && splitVector.back().empty())
  splitVector.pop_back();
```

Note the extra test for non-empty vector before accessing elements.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes, one has been largely commented on:

```
vector.end()->foo()
```

Invokes Undefined Behavior.

The other is more circumstantial:

```
vector.erase(vector.begin());
```

It is an error to call `erase` (UB) on the `end` iterator, and *if the `vector` is empty* then `vector.begin() == vector.end()`, invoking UB.

This error once again appears in the body of the `if`.

As far as I can tell, what you are looking for looks something like:

```
if (!vector.empty()) { vector.pop_front(); }
if (!vector.empty() && vector.back().length == 0) { vector.pop_back(); }
```

Note that there are idiomatic methods on `vector` which allow you no to fiddle with those awkward vectors, and also note that those used here require a non-empty vector to work.