# converting vector pointers and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I have grown very tired of looking for an answer, so this may be a repost.

I am trying to recreate heaps algorithm in cpp, and cannot figure out why the line is not working. When changing the value of what a pointer is pointing too you use the ->, or so I have been told, my compiler was saying that but is changing it's mind.
When you use .end, you should get a pointer to the next element in a vector, after the last, so I try to set it to an int from an array but the conversion from array of int's to vector of int's is problematic.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swapnumbers(int *arraytoswap [], int indexa, int indexb)
{
    int temp = *arraytoswap[indexa];
    *arraytoswap[indexa] = *arraytoswap[indexb];
    *arraytoswap[indexb] = temp;
}

void generate(int n, int heapArr[], vector<int> output[] )
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        int heaparrlen = (&heapArr + 1) - &heapArr;
        for (int i = 0; i = heaparrlen; i++)
        {
            ///this is the problamatic line
            output.end() -> heapArr[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        generate(n -1, heapArr, output);
        
        for (int i = 0; n-1; i++)
        {
            if (n%2 == 0)
            {
                swapnumbers(&heapArr, i, (n-1));
            }
            generate((n-1), heapArr, output);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int numberofnumbers;
    int tempint;
    cout<<"how many numbers will you input?"<<endl;
    cin>>numberofnumbers;
    
    vector<int> output;
    int input[numberofnumbers];
    
    for ( int i=0; i>numberofnumbers; i++)
    {
        cout<<"input the "<< i<<"the number"<<endl;
        cin>>tempint;
        input[i] = tempint;  
    }
    generate(numberofnumbers, input, &output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The condition in the for loop in your main() method is the wrong way round. It should be i<numberofnumbers; Did you ever try to actually run this code?

Comment: `int input[numberofnumbers];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have the number of elements denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value.  You're using `vector`, so why are you not using it here?  `std::vector<int> input(numberofnumbers);`?  So your program doesn't have any arrays in it -- it has a combination of `std::vector`, which is standard C++, and the fake `input` "array", which doesn't exist in C++.

Comment: Arrays have no methods for you to invoke. Mind you, `vector<int> output[]` probably shouldn't be an array in the first place.

Comment: To be honest, both function declarations are all topsy-turvy and need to be rewritten.  You're passing addresses of vectors when you should be passing a reference, then as noted this `vector<int> output[]` is wrong.  Add on what I've mentioned about using non-C++ syntax, etc.  The issue with the question is that an answer given would be a rewrite of the entire attempt you've made.  Don't know whether that would be acceptable.

Comment: One issue on that line, but not a solution in your specific case: [Problem with a deferencable iterator only with visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119957/). Possible solution for your specific case: [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) (but I didn't stare at the code long enough to guess what you are trying to do -- you really should explain your non-functioning code in words, rather than hope someone can figure out how the non-functioning code is intended to function).

Comment: I think you mean `*(output.end()) = heapArr[i]`? Note that `heaparrlen` will always be `1` there is no way to retrieve the size of an array from it's pointer, you need to pass in the size to the function (or just use `std::vector` as others have said

Answer (score 0):

Passing `vector<int> output[]` to a function is the same as passing `vector<int>* output`. Your code is trying to call `.end()` on a pointer to `vector<int>`, which is not doable, you should change that line to the below to assign the value to the end of the vector.

```cpp
*output->end() = heapArr[i];
```

Please note that it will only make the code compile, as it has other issues. Some of the other issues I noticed:

1. Why are you using C-like arrays instead of using just vectors?
2. `i > numberofnumbers` condition  in for loop should be `i < numberofnumbers`
3. `int heaparrlen = (&heapArr + 1) - &heapArr;` will always be 1, which is also the value of `n`, so it's unnecessary to create a new variable for the array  length
4. `vector<int> output` has 0 capacity and size
5. What you are currently doing in your code is constantly overwrite the end() of the vector,instead  of adding new elements, hich needs additional memory allocation and can be done by `push_back`. Note that `push_back` would work best with previous `reserve`.
6. Conditioning with assignment and `i = heaparrlen` is undesireable

**Edit:**

7. @PaulMcKenzie:

> int input[numberofnumbers]; -- This is not valid C++. Arrays in C++ must have the number of elements denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value. You're using vector, so why are you not using it here? std::vector input(numberofnumbers);
> 8. List item